# How to customize Selenium TestNG default report or create new HTML report?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, reporting-services, testng

I tried ReportNG, but it is not updating the report now & I found that ReportNG is no more used [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515453/reportng-html-report-not-updating/38587000#comment66608144_38587000).
I want to create a test report/customize TestNG report to gave to development team. I used Hybrid Framework for creating the project and followed [this tutorial](http://www.guru99.com/creating-keyword-hybrid-frameworks-with-selenium.html).

Comment: This is a vague question, what do you mean by `I tried ReportNG, but it is not updating the report now`?

Comment: @pArAs I generated report using ReportNG as mentoned [link](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/configuring-reportng-with-testng-to-generate-html-reports) & got the report as mentioned in it. But that report is generated only once.  After some changes I runned my project again but it is still showing the first report generated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customize the TestNG reports using Listeners and Reporters. Here is the [link](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) of documentation. It is not clear from a question what type of customization you want to do.

But I want to suggest better alternatives for reporting here. There are two most used libraries which generally used with Selenium.

1. [Allure Test Report](http://allure.qatools.ru/)
2. [Extent Report](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/).

I have not used Allure test reports but it seems to be good and widely used in  the community. I have had used Extent Reports in two projects and really happy with it. [Anshoo Arora](https://www.linkedin.com/in/anshooarora) has done the remarkable job. Documentation is very good with lot of example & code snippet. I would highly recommend it.

Comment: Hi @4M01... I mean I want to create report with custom fields like **Expected Result, Actual result, Result**,etc.

Comment: Seems like you came from QTP/UFT background :-) For your requirements, you need to do custom coding. It is not straight away answer as it will depend on a framework that you have to build for the project. But I was able to achieve what you are asking here using Extent Report.  Try using extent report and let me know

Comment: Okay @4M01. I will try using extent report. I was a manual tester,now switched to automation :-)

Comment: in that case just add QAF[https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/download.html] jar either in in dependency management or in class-path libraries it will enable you reporting features with your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

To customize selenium TestNG report, you can use testng listeners.

1. [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html): Log Result/Screenshot on test pass/fail/skip.
2. [IReporter](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html): To generate html report from xml suite results and log.

But as an alternative you can use [qaf-reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html).

It provides Detailed Live Reporting (Don`t need to wait for complete execution).

Comment: I agree, QAF reporting is very descriptive and you can get report without waiting for entire execution to get complete. Benefit of QAF reporting over other reporting is: It's live reporting as well as don't introduce out-of-memory issues in case of large test bed. We found many times execution crashed with large number of test case because of out-of-memory while generating report.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old thread, but these reports can be edited and custom reports can be made like below. I have also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309879/how-dataprovider-publish-the-test-data-into-html-report/47426325#47426325) how `TestHTMLReporter` can be edited . And if you would like to know , how index.html report is customized have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546020/how-to-override-the-index-html-report-in-testng/47557555#47557555) , where I have explained it in detail

With your `customReport` You'd have to implement `IReporter` , extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `generateReport` method if you want to implement a custom [`TestHTMLReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java) . For other reporters you may have to do things a bit  differently but the concept will remain the same. You'd achieve custom 'TestHTMLReporter' like below .

Create a `CustomReport.java` file in your project and copy-paste the whole content of `TestHTMLReporter.java` , change the name of file in `getOutputFile` method  and it would look like below

```
public class CustomReport  extends TestListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

     @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
                                   String outputDirectory) {

        }
   ...
   //paste the content of TestHTMLReporter.java here
   ...
   ...
```

Make sure all your imports are in place from `TestHTMLReporter.java`
Now, in this file  change as per your requirement . For ex: if you'd like to add the end time of each of the test then at the correct place in `generateTable` method  add the below snippet

```
// Test class
      String testClass = tr.getTestClass().getName();
       long testMillis = tr.getEndMillis();
        String testMillisString = Long.toString(testMillis);
      if (testClass != null) {
        pw.append("<br>").append("Test class Name: ").append(testClass);

         // this line to add end time in ms
        pw.append("<br>").append("End Time(ms): ").append(testMillisString); 
        // Test name
        String testName = tr.getTestName();
        if (testName != null) {
          pw.append(" (").append(testName).append(")");

        }
```

Then you'll get like below

[image]

Now, You'll get two reports one with default and the other with your file name.
The only thing now remains is switching off the default reporting listeners, so you get only one report. For that you can follow [this](http://testng.1065351.n5.nabble.com/How-to-disable-a-specific-default-reporter-and-listener-td23194.html) or you may search for solutions. Hope this helps