# How to Change Exception Message in TestNG Report

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

[need to change exception message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CSiX.png)[How to Change Exception Message in TestNG Report and change this Exception message into correct error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag2Lp.png)
this report using different code for TestNG report.

Using This Code., Link Given..
Link:
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-customize-emailable-html-report-example

Comment: the link is to change time format in the html not for the message. Your message is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize Selenium TestNG default report or create new HTML report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654254/how-to-customize-selenium-testng-default-report-or-create-new-html-report)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize it with meaningful Message, By using Try Catch mechanism

Where you can construct code with try{} block and in catch(Exception e){} if you keep stack trace then only it will retrieve default Exception message as Shown.

Like:

```
try {
   "Your Code" ;
} 
catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Custom User defined message");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you don't trace Exception with  e.printStackTrace(); then it will retrieve only your user define message in Console as well as TestNG Report.